# Separate frontend and backend with Yii framework

Tags: php, yii, frontend, backend

What is the best and the most right way to separate front-end and back-end with Yii framework?

Comment: That's a very important question. It could be a bit more detailed, but I don't understand why it was voted down.

Comment: @schmunk maybe it was downvoted because as it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for Q&A format and is overly broad. This question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. The terms used in the question "the best" and "the most right way" are too subjective. Good questions are often supported by references and related examples so that they can be objectively answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no offical way to do this in Yii 1.x, but there are several approaches.

Have a look at [yiinitializer advanced](https://github.com/tonydspaniard/yiinitializr-advanced), to get an impression how `frontend` and `backend` are separated here. They are more or less two applications sharing a `common` folder.

My project [Phundament](http://phundament.com) takes a simpler approach, just by switching themes depending on controller routes with the [multi-theme](https://github.com/schmunk42/multi-theme) extension.

Answer (score 0):

See nice article here http://habrahabr.ru/post/117457/ .
English version available here: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/63/organize-directories-for-applications-with-front-end-and-back-end-using-webapplicationend-behavior/
It's main goal is attaching special behaviors.
I like this way most of all.